# Find Duplicate/Repeated or Unique words in file spanning across multiple lines

Tags: find, duplicates

in Linux, I have a text file which have duplicate words like this

```
abc line 1
xyz zzz
123 456
abc end line
```

Now I want to print only all DUPLICATE words (which is abc)
how ?

Comment: Count all words, display those that occur at least twice?

Comment: Do you want to do this using some program like a text editor OR do you want to write a program in a language? If it's a language, what language do you use?

Comment: I want bash script or sed or awk, or something like , just to print duplicate words from both file. simple.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can tokenize the words with `grep -wo` and find consecutive duplicates with `uniq -d`, add `-c` to count the number of duplicates, e.g.:

```
grep -wo '[[:alnum:]]\+' infile | sort | uniq -cd
```

Output:

```
2 abc
2 line
```